# Remove a JSON string which is in list using python3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to remove the {'settings': 'Val'} from the dictionary where some JSON part in the list, I was able to remove with var['a']['b'][2] but I want to delete 'settings' by looping through 'b'

Whats are the ways I can delete the 'settings'.

```
var = {
    'a': {
        'b': [
            {
                'check': 'val'
            },
            {
                'alerts': 'val'
            },
            {
                'settings': 'val'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```
for items in var['a']['b']:
    del items['settings']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sree/PycharmProjects/test/app1.py", line 59, in <module>
    del items['settings']
KeyError: 'settings
```

```
## tried this and getting the same error

for items in var['a']['b']:
    items.pop('settings')
    print(var)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sree/PycharmProjects/test/app1.py", line 70, in <module>
    items.pop('settings')
KeyError: 'settings'
```

Comment: The problem you have is that you are iterating over all of the 3 dictionaries. Only one of those dictionaries has the key 'settings'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter out the dict using list comprehension:

```
var = {
    'a': {
        'b': [
            {
                'check': 'val'
            },
            {
                'alerts': 'val'
            },
            {
                'settings': 'val'
            }
        ]
    }
}


var['a']['b'] = [val for val in var['a']['b'] if 'settings' not in val]

import json
print(json.dumps(var, indent=4))
```

Print:

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": [
            {
                "check": "val"
            },
            {
                "alerts": "val"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```